# Buildbot - Traceback while polling for changes issue

Tags: python, polling, traceback, buildbot

I'm running on Windows 7 x64. I followed the install documentation on Buildbot and did some research on the issue I'm having and haven't found a solution yet. When I do a force build, everything works fine. I'm using GitPoller. When it tries to poll for changes, an exception is thrown; why? Let me know if I can supply any more information. Here's what I'm getting on the master's twistd.log every 5 minutes:

```
2014-10-09 00:19:53-0700 [-] while polling for changes
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.9-py2.7.egg\buildbot\util\misc.py", line 54, in start
       d = self.method()
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.9-py2.7.egg\buildbot\changes\base.py", line 70, in doPoll
       d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.poll)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 139, in maybeDeferred
       result = f(*args, **kw)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
       return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
   --- <exception caught here> ---
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
       result = g.send(result)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.9-py2.7.egg\buildbot\changes\gitpoller.py", line 147, in poll
       yield self._dovccmd('init', ['--bare', self.workdir])
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildbot-0.8.9-py2.7.egg\buildbot\changes\gitpoller.py", line 292, in _dovccmd
       [command] + args, path=path, env=os.environ)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\utils.py", line 176, in getProcessOutputAndValue
       reactor)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\utils.py", line 30, in _callProtocolWithDeferred
       reactor.spawnProcess(p, executable, (executable,)+tuple(args), env, path)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 358, in spawnProcess
       return Process(self, processProtocol, executable, args, env, path)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_dumbwin32proc.py", line 195, in __init__
       raise OSError(pwte)
   exceptions.OSError: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Also, here's the relevant portion of my config file:

```
from buildbot.changes.gitpoller import GitPoller
c['change_source'] = []
c['change_source'].append(GitPoller(
        repourl='https://github.com/solstice333/BuildbotTest.git', 
        branch='master',
        pollinterval=300))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue with HgPoller. Try to specify full path to git

```
c['change_source'].append(GitPoller(
    gitbin='full/path/to/git.exe',
    repourl='https://github.com/solstice333/BuildbotTest.git', 
    branch='master',
    pollinterval=300))
```

I think something wrong with twisted - this dont work with same error

PS Twisted use win32process.CreateProcess and MSDN says about it first argument: The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path.

```
from twisted.internet import utils
utils.getProcessOutputAndValue("hg.exe", ['init', "test_dir"])
```